# Disable "space+shift" in Sublime Text

Tags: macos, sublimetext

I want to disable the "space+shift" thing in Sublime Text, it creates something that looks exactly like a space unless marked, and it messes upp all my scripts because I always accidentally type it. I was not able to find anything like "space+shift" or "shift+space" inside the sublime-keymap.

Comment: My Language/Region settings are English/USA and I see nothing to disable because "space+shift" is not defined and is nothing more then two keys being pressed, which on my system only produces a space.  Additionally, looking at the file in a hex editor shows it as hex 20 which is nothing more then a space.  That said, this may not be the case in other Language/Region settings, so you might need to provide more information especially what exactly you mean by "and it messes upp all my scripts".

Comment: Nothing to add to user3439894's comment except that you should add a screenshot of the messed up scripts.

Comment: I forgot to add I tried  "shift+space" as well as "space+shift" and the results are the same, a space (hex 20) being typed.

Comment: @klanomath What's interesting about seeing a screenshot of the scripts? Sorry if I didn't explain well, but it looks the exact same but it doesn't work the same. If I want to match a string that's exactly `string `(string+space) and I accidentally pressed that weird character, I will match `string `(string+weird character) and that messes my scripts up.

Comment: @DisplayName As user3439894 I can't reproduce the behavior of Sublime you describe.  I also get 0x20 as result with the one or the other key(-combo).

Comment: I typed it and opened it with an hex editor and got "C2 A0".@klanomath

Comment: @DisplayName I've created a Sublime document with the content *abcd(shift+space)(new-line)abcd(space)(new-line)* and examined the file with Hexfiend. The two lines are identical.

Comment: For me it appears as "¬†".

Comment: Are you sure the issue is shift+space? This sounds to me like [alt+space issue](https://coderwall.com/p/myfhmg/dealing-with-alt-space-non-breakable-space-in-sublime-text-2-on-os-x), which inserts a non-breaking space ( which doesn't look entirely identical to normal space ).  As far as I can tell, shift+space just creates a normal space.

Comment: @Joonas maybe alt+space has, for some reason, been remapped to shift+space? But yeah, I followed that guide and replace alt+space with shift+space and the issue is fixed now. If you want to, you could add that as an answer and I would accept it.

Comment: You can answer it youself, if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

On my system I can't reproduce the behavior of Sublime described by the OP. The problem may be related to an interfering third-party app/process.

One possible solution - configuring a new keycode with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) to avoid the problem - is outlined below.

To disable or modify <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> in Sublime just remap the key combo with Karabiner. Usually you have to define an app in */Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Resources/appdef.xml* if you want to adjust/modify an app-only shortcut. Since the appdef list already contains *Sublime Text* you can immediately add a new remapping.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   Example (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> -> <kbd>Space</kbd>):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
     <item>
       <name>Enable at only SUBLIMETEXT</name>
       <item>
         <name>Shift+Space to Space</name>
         <identifier>remap.app_sublime_shiftspace2space</identifier>
         <only>SUBLIMETEXT</only>
         <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_SHIFT, KeyCode::SPACE</autogen>
       </item>
     </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the *Sublime Text* remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.